# localStorage is not defined, nextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am getting localstorage is not defined error when page loads.

this is the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage) {
      const storageView = localStorage.getItem("calendarView");
      setViewCalendar(storageView ? JSON.parse(storageView) : "Day");
    }
  }, [localStorage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewCalendar !== null && typeof window !== "undefined"  && localStorage) {
      localStorage.setItem("calendarView", JSON.stringify(viewCalendar));
    }
  }, [viewCalendar]);
```

Comment: Is this code located in a component ?

Comment: I think you should not use `localStorage` as a dependency of first useEffect hook. please test it again after removing `localStorage` in dependencies of useEffect.  like following. useEffect(() => {...}, []);

Comment: Can you please add details like, calendarView is String or JSON ? Are you trying to initialize value from local storage on load ?